# Print array of reversed strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want this code to print each word backwards, but is not printing the last word, I guess I'm missing something very basic here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int l;
    printf("lenght: ");
    scanf("%i",&l);
    char str[l][100];
    int lenght[l];

    for(int i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        printf("%i : ",i);
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
        lenght[i] = strlen(str[i]);
    }

    for(int i=l-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        for(int j=lenght[i-1]; j>=0; j--)
        {
            printf("%c",str[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You need to use`i >= 0` in this for loop: `for(int i=l-1; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: Or, `for(int i=l; i-- >0;)` for the outer loop, and `for(int j=lenght[i]; j-- >0;)` for the inner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i > 0` and `lenght[i - 1]` are causing the problem. Also consider using `putchar` to print a single `char` and `size_t` to represent size of a string:

```
for (size_t i = l; i--;) {
  for (size_t j = lenght[i]; j--;) {
    putchar(str[i][j]);
  }
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: why did you changed your answer, the other one worked perfectly fine, there's any difference ?

Comment: @user29893 Either way is fine. This way seems more clear to me (no need for the magic number `-1`)

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem `for(int i=l-1; i>0; i--)`.Currently the `0` index string is never processed. Set condition to `i >= 0` to include `0` also.

The inner loop initialization also need to be changed to `j = lenght[i] - 1`.